# How can i create dynamicly in ng-model using variable

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

```
<input ng-model="company.title_{{selectedLang}}"
       type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control">
```

I have already try:

```
<input ng-model="company.title_[selectedLang]"
       type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control">
```

It doesn't work.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: what are you asking for? be more specific when asking!

Comment: Give us more details

Comment: I have my database columns title_en,title_de,title_el
And I want to retrieve the data from my datatabase and also post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!-- REPLACE this
<input ng-model="company.title_{{selectedLang}}"
       type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control">

-->

 <!-- WITH this -->
 <input ng-model="company['title_'+selectedLang]"
        type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control">
```